# Why again simply empty app.Run() does we need?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm practicing on a simple web api by C# in which I try to see how pipeline goes on. But if I don't add  simply empty `app.Run()` at the end of file, the program terminates immediately, that is, return 0 without running browser. If I write, it works and prints as expected. **Must it be at the end of file even if there is `app.Run(blablabla)`?** As far as I know, `app.Run()` is the terminator delegate.

Simple `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();



app.Use(async (context, next) =>    
{    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 1st app.Use()\n");    
  await next();    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 1st app.Use()\n");    
});    
    
app.Use(async (context, next) =>    
{    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\n");    
  await next();    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\n");    
});    
    
app.Run(async (context) =>    
{    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from 1st app.Run()\n");    
});    
    
// the following will never be executed    
app.Run(async (context) =>    
{    
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from 2nd app.Run()\n");    
});    


// app.Run(); if we comment in, it works. This style doesn't work.
```

Comment: Note that the `RunExtensions.Run` extension method you are using for `app.Run(async (context) => ...` is not doing what you would intuitively expect. Despite its name, it's actually not running anything. From [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-6.0): "_Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline._" Yeah, you read that right, despite it's name, it's not running your app, it's just adding stuff to the request pipeline. It pretty much is some kind of `app.Use`.

Comment: Here is the relevant source code for the RunExtensions.Run extension method. Note that it really doesn't do anything but calling app.Use: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e40c0fd4c87f82de4b685d050df542a52d4fa816/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/RunExtensions.cs#L18-L31 (Don't ask me who had the bright idea to name that extension method "Run"...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace so what is the diff?

Comment: What do you mean? Didn't i just explain in my comments that `app.Run(async (context) => ...` isn't running anything, that its purpose is _not_ to run something, and that its name is misleading? (Also the answer given below pretty much explains the same...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace o what is the diff btw app.Use(blabla) and app.Run(blabla) then?

Comment: Look at my second comment. That should enlighten you. Or maybe it makes you face-palm, which would be an appropriate reaction ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `app.Run(...)` where you pass in a delegate are calling [this extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which only sets up a delegate to be called later when requests come in.

> Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline.

The calls to `app.Run()` where you provide no argument are calling [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication.run?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which actually runs the application.

> Runs an application and block the calling thread until host shutdown.

One can certainly question the wisdom of giving these two methods the same name, when they have fundamentally different purposes.

Comment: I honestly never would've guessed that any overload or extension called  `Run` wouldn't actually run something. That naming is utterly abhorrent.

Comment: @jhmckimm, absolutely agree, especially if you look at the source code of the extention method. Aside from some sanity checks, the only thing it does is calling app.Use. Ba-dum-tss...