# Asp.Net Core Middleware: Run() and Run(RequestDelegate)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently learning middleware in asp.net core. I tried to write some texts in the response so that I could see the flow of request and response:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 1st app.Use()\n");
    await next();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 1st app.Use()\n");
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\n");
    await next();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\n");
});

app.Run();
```

After I hit the execute button, it threw an exception saying `System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.`

I cannot figure out why it happened. There is no action of altering http header or stuff alike in the code. After some trying, I found that the following worked:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 1st app.Use()\\n");
    await next();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 1st app.Use()\\n");
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\\n");
    await next();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("After Invoke from 2nd app.Use()\\n");
});

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("From Run()\\n");
});

app.Run();
```

The website showed the result I want but it confused me. `Run()` will terminate the pipeline and create the response, and no middleware will be executed after it.

Then why in this occasion two `Run()` works? Is there any difference between a `Run()` and a `Run(...)` with some actions?

And when I deleted the `Run()` without action at the end of the code, the application was terminated by itself.

I used the default template of asp.net core with .net 7 and wrote nothing other than these codes. Could anyone tell me the reason of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are writing to the response stream with the `context.Response.WriteAsync` lines and then your requests attempt to set the status code (e.g. 200, 404 etc) which is not possible once you have started outputting data to the client.

Comment: (^^^ unless buffering is enabled, but... don't do that unless you have to) - maybe use the *logger* rather than the response for writing these messages?

Comment: _Is there any difference between a Run() and a Run(...) with some actions?_ -> [Run(...) vs Run()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640910/7450780)

Comment: @DenisMicheal Thanks a lot! Now I know why I need to add a Run() at the end.

Comment: A middleware is meant to be part of the chain that handles HTTP requests. You can not test middlewares without at least one mapped HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @MikeJ82 Technically there is an endpoint of sorts, in the `app.Run` the framework is there to handle requests that result in a 404. That is why the first block of code gives the error. The second block of code succeeds because there is no call to `await next()` so the pipeline ends there.

Comment: I trust the above comment already explained very well. Just sharing some related sources code for checking. In the default template for .net 7 MVC, we have `app.UseRouting();app.UseAuthorization();` and many other clauses which are all [using middleware there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0), and in the end we have `app.run()` to run the app. here's the code for useRouting.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e07adfec59003776702370fe2091e731a323c67f/src/Http/Routing/src/Builder/EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L62C38-L62C63    and    https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e07adfec59003776702370fe2091e731a323c67f/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs#L59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, middleware components are executed in the order they are added to the pipeline. When you use **app.Run()** without any parameters, it signifies the termination of the middleware pipeline. Any middleware components added after **app.Run()** will not be executed because the request will be handled by the terminal middleware defined in **app.Run()**.

In your first example, you have two **app.Use()** middleware components followed by **app.Run()**. When the request comes in, it passes through the first middleware, then the second, and finally reaches the terminal middleware defined by **app.Run()**. However, since you have **two app.Run()** calls, it confuses the ASP.NET Core runtime because it's not sure which terminal middleware to use.

In your second example, you have only **one app.Run()** with a **lambda expression** defining the terminal middleware action. This means that the ASP.NET Core runtime knows exactly which middleware to use as the terminal middleware, and it correctly terminates the pipeline after executing that middleware.

If you delete the **app.Run()** without an action, the ASP.NET Core runtime doesn't know what to do after processing the middleware components, so it terminates the application because there's no terminal middleware defined to handle the request.

So:↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
**Use app.Run()** with **a lambda expression** defining the terminal middleware action if you want to specify custom terminal middleware.
Avoid using **multiple app.Run()** calls without any action, as it can lead to confusion and unexpected behavior in the middleware pipeline.